# How can I get zbar to detect a qr code with a dark background?

Tags: python-3.x, qr-code, zbar

I have been searching and search for a way to detect qr codes that have a dark background (white text) using zbar + opencv + python 3.

In the zbar documentation, I don't find anything about this capability either.

Is there a way to detect qr codes with a dark background using zbar in python 3?

If not - can you guys and gals recommend another python 3 library that I can use?

thanks.

Comment: Do you have an example of such a QR code? According to the QR code specification, a dark and a light color must be used, the lighter one for the background. Possibly, your QR code is invalid.

Comment: The QR code is valid. I can detect it with node js. However I want to do it in python.